# app crashes if gps never ben used

Tags: android

im working on this app that uses gps to show position on google map. 
Bu there seem to be a problem, causing the app to crash at start if the gps is turned of in settings and if gps never ben used before. 
Other then that the app seem to work as it should

can anyone see anything that might be the cause ?

Here is my code

```
    public class WebPageLoader extends Activity implements LocationListener{
    public static String Android_ID = null;
    final Activity activity = this;
    private Location mostRecentLocation;


private void getLocation() {

    LocationManager locationManager =
      (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria,true);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 2000, 500, this);      
    mostRecentLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

  }

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    //AdManager.setTestDevices( new String[] { AdManager.TEST_EMULATOR } );
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    //getLocation();
    Android_ID = Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID);

            /* Kan man kickstarta GPS såhär ? */
            //mostRecentLocation.getLatitude();                 
            getLocation();


    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    /** Allows JavaScript calls to access application resources **/
    webView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(), "android16");
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)
        {
            activity.setTitle("Letar poliskontroller");
            activity.setProgress(progress * 100);


            if(progress == 100)
                activity.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
        }
    });


    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl)
        {
            // Handle the error
        }



        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
        {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    });

    if (Locale.getDefault().getLanguage().equals("sv")){
    //webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/android.html");
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/findgps_sv.html");
    }else{
    //webView.loadUrl("http://m.bryggplatsen.se/android/polis/index.php");
    //webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/android_en.html");
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/findgps_en.html");
    }



}
    /** Sets up the interface for getting access to Latitude and Longitude data from device
     **/




private class JavaScriptInterface {
    public double getLatitude(){
        return mostRecentLocation != null ? mostRecentLocation.getLatitude() : Double.NaN;
    }

    public double getLongitude(){
        return mostRecentLocation != null ? mostRecentLocation.getLongitude() : Double.NaN;
    }


    public String getAndroid_ID(){
        return Android_ID;
    }

     public void sharethisapp(){
     startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharespotIntent(), "Share this warning"));
     }
  }


@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    getLocation();
    //android16();

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    MenuItem item = menu.add("Close menu");
    item = menu.add("Shut down");
    item.setIcon(R.drawable.exit);

    item = menu.add("Share");
    item.setIcon(R.drawable.m_share);


    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if (item.getTitle() == "Shut down") {
        System.exit(0);
        finish();
    }

    if (item.getTitle() == "Share") {
        if (Locale.getDefault().getLanguage().equals("sv")){
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent(), "Dela denna app"));
        }else{
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent(), "Share this app"));
        }
    }
    return true;
}

private Intent shareIntent() {
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.setType("text/plain");      
    if (Locale.getDefault().getLanguage().equals("sv")){
        shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Testa denna android app...");
        return shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "http://www.bryggplatsen.se/android/polisapp/index.php");
    }else{
        shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Try this cool android app...");
        return shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "http://www.bryggplatsen.se/android/polisapp/index_en.php");         
    }

}


private Intent sharespotIntent() {
    Intent sharespotIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sharespotIntent.setType("text/plain");      
if (Locale.getDefault().getLanguage().equals("sv")){
    sharespotIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, " la just upp en ny varning i appen Polisradar");
    return sharespotIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "http://www.bryggplatsen.se/android/polisapp/warn.php?lat=" + mostRecentLocation.getLatitude() + "&lng=" + mostRecentLocation.getLongitude() + "");
}else{
    sharespotIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, " just added a new warning in the app Policeradar");
    return sharespotIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "http://www.bryggplatsen.se/android/polisapp/warn_en.php?lat=" + mostRecentLocation.getLatitude() + "&lng=" + mostRecentLocation.getLongitude() + "");       
    }
}
```

}

Comment: It might be helpful to post the logcat.

Comment: Youre right... ill update with logcat

Comment: Here is the logcat, filtered warnings and errors http://www.bryggplatsen.se/android/polisapp/logcat_eclipse.txt

Comment: Here's the error that's relevant: 12-18 12:41:05.137: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(292): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{polis.koll/polis.koll.WebPageLoader}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: provider==null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no location providers that match your `Criteria`, and so the location provider you use with `LocationManager` is `null`. You will need to handle that case in your code (e.g., prompt the user to enable GPS).

Comment: hmm. ok thanks alot, ill google some if i can find out how to acomplish that

Comment: thanks again, i googled some and found this helpful http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/10/check-and-prompt-user-to-enable-gps.html

Answer (score 0):

set

```
try {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(locationManager.getBestProvider(yourcriteria, true), 100, 1, gpsListener);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                alertMessage("le recepteur est peut être descativé l'application \n  ne peut pas calculer les points GPS \n vous devez les saisir ");
        }
```